# Restrict Search not to show deleted managed property value

Tags: search-results, keywordquery

The default SharePoint behavior is to also search documents which have been deleted unless the content has been re-crawled or index is reset. 
I am using a KeywordQuery to search items with a particular managed property and I don't want the deleted items to show up in the result even if content has not been re-crawled  or reset.

```
    query.QueryText = string.Format("Barcode:\"{0}\"", "ABC123");
    query.ResultTypes |= ResultType.RelevantResults;
    query.SelectProperties.Add("Barcode");
```

The only way I am able to achieve it so far is to add the "Path" property and then checking if the resulting SPListItem is not null.

```
     query.SelectProperties.Add("Path");
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a high ratio of queries compared to deletes, then you might want to add an event receiver which calls [CrawlRuleCollection.RemoveFromResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.crawlrulecollection.removefromresults.aspx) upon deletion of an item